# Series development of laurent in a defined domain

Tags: summation, series-expansion, coefficients

I am trying to correct some bills for laurent series with mathematica, but the output I am getting at the moment is not the best.
For example, I have this function
$$\frac{1}{z^2 + 9}$$
to develop at the point $z_0 = 3i$ in region $0 < |z - 3i| < 6$.

What I have tried so far is

```
Series [1 / (z ^ 2 + 9), {z, 3 I, 10}]
```

but this only returns me 10 terms of the series.

Then I tried

```
sumRule = 
  Inactive[Series][f_, {x_, x0_, n_}] :> 
   Inactive[Sum][
    Assuming[{Element[k, Integers], k >= 0}, 
     SeriesCoefficient[f, {z, 3 I, k}] (x - x0)^k // 
      FullSimplify], {k, 0, n}];

n = Infinity;

f[z_] = 1/(z^2 + 9);

Inactive[Series][f[z], {z, 3 I, n}] /. sumRule
```

The latter returns
$$\underset{k=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}6^{-k-2} (3+i z)^k$$
which comes close to the expected result:
$$\frac{1}{6i} \frac{1}{z-3i} + \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{-1}{(6i)^{n+2}} (z-3i)^n$$
but it is not this complete and I don't know why.
I also haven't specified anywhere in which region to develop.
So how can I get the correct result and maybe even specify the region?

Comment: "but this only returns me 10 terms of the series"  What exactly do you mean by this?  I am asking because you did ask for 10 terms?

Comment: Because it would serve me up to infinity, but rightly does not print infinite terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

c[k_] = SeriesCoefficient[1/(z^2 + 9), {z, 3 I, k}]
```

[image]

```
sum = Inactive[Sum][c[k]*(z - 3*I)^k, {k, -1, Infinity}] // 
 Simplify[#, {k >= -1, Element[k, Integers]}] &
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
sum // Activate

(* 1/(9 + z^2) *)
```

**EDIT:** Your "expected result" does not equal the original function

```
sum2 = HoldForm[1/(6 I) 1/(z - 3 I) +
   Inactive[Sum][-1/((6 I)^(n + 2)) (z - 3 I)^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]]
```

[image]

```
sum2 // ReleaseHold // Activate // Simplify

(* (6 + I z)/(81 + 36 I z - 3 z^2) *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and for the correction. However, this procedure does not seem universal, for example SeriesCoefficient does not seem to work with the function (z ^ 2 (z - 1)) / (Sin [1 / (z - 1)]) and I don't know why.